# React useState keep giving me undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-state

```
const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState();

onClick={function(){
                                setUrlList(item.num);
                                console.log(item.num);
                          
                                callDayList();
                            }}
```

1. what is this code about?

there is a table, and if I click a url, it gives item.num(1,2,3...). and through the callDayList func, the number goes to backend(node.js).

2. what is the problem?

the problem is the state urlList, does not have proper number, but only undefined. the outcome of console.log is only undefined. however, on chrome, I found that the state is changing correctly, however the speed of change bit slow and the value of state showing me the state of last click(not sure you understand, on second click, the value of state is the first click's state.).

3.what I have tried?

I have searched internet, and I think this is the problem of rendering. because useState does not apply changes immediately. and I think this is the reason keep showing me undefined, because on first click, there is no value in state(and on second click, it shows the value of state of first click.)

one of the solution was code like ...item.num (add"...")  but, did not work.
second was put the state in a var, like  `var _num = urlList` and `console.log(_num)` but also did not work.

actually, I have already solved this problem by not using state, but put the item.num in a var and send it to backend, but I want to understand why it is not working through useState.

Comment: can you please add more code?

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

`setUrlList(item.num);` this is asynchronous. You need to use a `useEffect` hook to do anything that should happen when `urlList` changes.
Try below:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState();

const callDayList = () => { 
     console.log(urlList); 
     Axios.post('localhost:3001/api/get',{ passNum : urlList, });
}

useEffect(() => {callDayList();}, [urlList]);
```

In your element,

```
onClick={function(){ setUrlList(item.num);}}
```

Comment: @edei, I have updated the answer. It should log the `urlList` when it changes and then sent to the api. May be var will also work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch for changes in your state. See example with your code (mock data) https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-cherry-1c8b6

`useEffect` is watching for the state changes of `urlList`

As you can also see the first console outside of the `useEffect`, is giving `undefined`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState();
  const items = [1, 2, 3]
  console.log(urlList);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(urlList);
  }, [urlList])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map(item => {
        return (
          <p onClick={function(){
            setUrlList(item);
            console.log(item);
        }}>Item {item}</p>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks! I have not seen useEffect yet. I going to study more!

Comment: Yes and please check out [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) where you can use functions that depend on state changes, which is useful!