# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'callDayList'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: use-effect

[React useState keep giving me undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788860/react-usestate-keep-giving-me-undefined)
this is my last questions, and it helped me a lot.

I had a problem of updating of state, and I understood the cause. but it caused me another problem.

```
const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState(0);

    const callDayList = () =>{
        
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/get',{    
        passNum :urlList,
        });
    };
    useEffect(() => {callDayList();},[urlList]);
```

this is my code, and when urlList changes, I want to execute callDayList and pass the value of urlList. when I study about useEffect, I found the problem, if I include urlList inside callDayList, it will cause infinite re-rendering error. but I want to pass the value of urlList when it changes. how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Warning is thrown since you are not using `urlList` in the useEffect hook. Make use of the variable or update `callDayList` method.

```js
const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState(0);

const callDayList = (list) =>{ 
       Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/get',{    
       passNum :list,
    });
};
useEffect(() => {callDayList(urlList);},[urlList]);
```

or

```
const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState(0);

const callDayList = () =>{ 
       Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/get',{    
       passNum :urlList,
     });
};
useEffect(callDayList,[urlList]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `React.useCallback`.

Right now, `callDayList` changes on every render which is one of the reasons why you can't add it to the dependency list. To prevent this, wrap the function in a `useCallback`:

```
const callDayList = React.useCallback(() => {
  Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/get', {    
    passNum: urlList,
  });
}, [urlList]);
```

Now, `callDayList` will change only when `urlList` changes. Now you can rewrite your `useEffect`:

```
React.useEffect(callDayList, [callDayList]);
```

Now `callDayList` is called only when it changes, and it changes only when `urlList` changes - which is what you want.